# Python working substraction in function

Tags: python

I want to make a function called bank. I have input called money that ask you how much money you want to take out from second variable called "storage". Storage = 10000, if storage > 0: make substraction storage - money.
If storage <= 0:
print("We dont have money"), and quit that function

```
def bank():
    money = int(input("How much money you want? "))
    storage = 10000
    if storage > 0:
        storage = storage - money
        print(storage)
        bank()
    if storage <= 0:
        print("we dont have money")
        quit()
bank()
```

The problem is if money == 1000 so storage == 9000, but if second time money == 2000, storage should show 7000, but shows 8000

Comment: You are always assigning storage = 10000 in line 3

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call `bank()` recursively it resets storage to 10000. So you would need to initialize it outside of the funtion.

So

```
def bank(storage):
    money = int(input("How much money you want? "))
    if storage > 0:
        storage = storage - money
        print(storage)
        bank(storage)
    if storage <= 0:
        print("we dont have money")
        quit()

storage = 10000
bank(storage)
```

Comment: Thanks i thought that might be something with that variable